# Macbook Pro Late-2011, Mountain Lion, when it sleeps, devices don't wake

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Made the upgrade to Mountain lion when it came out, but since the upgrade I have noticed something occurring when my laptop goes to sleep be it idling or me putting it in a sleep mode, when I go to wake the laptop almost every time anything hooked into the USB ports don't respond and remain dormant as if the laptop was still in a sleep mode.

Example one of the places I hook my Mac up has a wired USB keyboard, and a USB to VGA monitor connector which doesn't respond when I wake the laptop. Or another place where I have 2 USB Monitor connections, a USB based harddrive toaster. All of which stop responding after the laptop sleeps. I have to pull the USB's out and plug them back in to make them work again and only after I wake the laptop.

So I am wondering is there some new power settings I am missing somewhere, that don't turn the USB on after idle? Everything worked just fine prior to the Mountain Lion Upgrade so I know its nothing to do with that.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you already found this, but ....
System Preferences/Energy Saver 
has a checkbox "Wake for network access'
The help says:
Select this option if you want other users to be able to access your computer’s shared resources, such as shared printers or iTunes playlists, even when your computer is in sleep mode.

Comment: Unfortunately not particularly helpful to the cause. Also just as unfortunate I am still suffering the same problems. Where anything USB connected when the laptop falls asleep. Upon waking it, none of the USB connected devices act like they are connected, I usually have to unplug them and plug them back in for them to start working again.

Comment: @paul-churchill’s answer does absolutely miss the point. @chris you might want to rephrase the question title to attract more viewers (just a hint)